# iOS Google Sign In error

Tags: ios, google-signin

I'm trying to implement a google sign in button, when I add the following lines to my AppDelegate.swift file, I get this error:

Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : AnyObject]' with an index of type 'String'

Any ideas what's wrong with this code? By the way, this code is just copied and pasted from google page at:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?configured&ver=swift

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
    openURL url: NSURL, options options: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
            sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey],
            annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])
}
```

[image: iOS Google Sign In error]

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the error happens at this point? What line is highlighted by Xcode when the exception occurs? If it is indeed in this function, what's the value of `options`?

Comment: Thanks for the response jcaron. Yes, after I added the line I readily got this error. I have attached a picture for better reference to see which line is highlighted. Also, xcode is giving this extra explanation to the error: "Overloads for 'subscript' exist with these partially matching parameter lists: (DictionaryIndex<Key, Value>), (Key), (Range<Self.Index>), (Self.Index)"

Comment: By the way, how should I check the value of options?

Comment: What's the warning on "options" 2 lines above? Also, you'll want to fix the other warnings (you have 12 warnings in your project).

Comment: You can't see the value of options as your code isn't running. I thought you had a runtime error, not a compile error.

Comment: The warning is "Extraneous duplicate parameter name; 'options' already has an argument label", but even after I remove one of the "options", same error still stays

Comment: I'm more of an Objective-C that Swift guy, so I'm not familiar with the details of the syntax, but after a quick test, just removing one of the two "options" seems to fix the issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

handleURL is looking for arguments of type "String" for sourceApplication and annotation, but options is providing "AnyObject."  Casting those dictionary values to "String" oughtta do it.

Try this:

**Update: Swift 3**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey: Any]) -> Bool
   return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
       sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
       annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation] as? String)
}
```

**Swift 2**

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
    openURL url: NSURL, options: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
            sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as? String,
            annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey] as? String)
}
```

This took me forever, too.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Worked like a charm. :) Awesome.

Answer (score 8):

**Xcode 8 Swift 3**

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
  return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(
  url,
  sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String,
  annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
}
```

Comment: I guess it would be better to add some note about what this code does. Thanks.